Unable to reposition OneDrive icon in explorer
I've tried to reposition the OneDrive icon in explorer by changing the sort order in for OneDrive in the windows registry.
Yet, OneDrive always shows up at the top of the list in the sidebar, in a section of it's own, dedicated to just OneDrive.
This isn't the behavior that I am looking for. Is there any way in which I can reposition OneDrive as indicated in the screenshot?

